# Input Doesn't Work as Expected When Overlaying a Fragment in Main activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I used this code to overlay a fragment over all of my views.

```
statusList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment fragment = new DetailedInformerFragment();

            FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(android.R.id.content,fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

The fragment gets overlayed but when I start touching the screen, it goes through the fragment. For example, there was a textbox in the main activity. When I overlay the fragment over the main activity, I touch where the textbox was, even though I don't see it and I am not supposed to, the keyboard will pop up.

My question is how do I prevent user input to the other views except the fragment which is the only thing the user can see.

Comment: Although we wont be able to tell for certain without seeing more code it sounds as though you never removed the original content before applying the fragment.

Comment: I didn't, is there a way to do so? And my code is quite extensive I wouldn't want to post a bunch of files. But if need be, it's quite possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using,

```
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

try using,

```
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
```

Because you have added a fragment on-top of other content they are essentially both there, which is why your interface is getting confused. By using replace, you replace any existing fragment with the new one so they do not both exist on the interface at the same time.

A `FrameLayout` is probably the best practice for a container for a fragment because a `FrameLayout` will only allow a single child element thus enforcing this behaviour of not allowing multiple fragments/layouts into the same UI space.

Further reading:

- [Android API Guide - Managing Fragments & replace()](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Managing)
- [FrameLayout API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: It didn't work, probably because there is no fragment below it. Should I encapsulate what I have inside of a fragment? What would that do in terms of performance and such?

Comment: @BayaniJ - Yes, that would be wise. I would tend not to mix up space that will contain a Fragment and space that contains standard Activity elements. Take a look at `FrameLayout` for this.